# IOCP WSARecv always return error 10022

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, iocp, io-completion-ports

I'm using IOCP on Windows. Previously I used method `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` to poll the queue and everything was fine. But when I decided to refactor the logic in the way to utilize completion routine with `WSARecv` call it always fails with the error `WSAEINVAL` (10022). This code is in thread created with `CreateTread`

```
int flags = 0;
m_iocport = CreateIoCompletionPort(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, NULL, 0);
handle = CreateIoCompletionPort(clientSocket, m_iocport, 0, 0);
OVERLAPPED_EX *over = new OVERLAPPED_EX();
result = WSARecv(clientSocket, &over->m_wsabuf, 1, NULL, &flags, over, WorkerRoutine);
```

And the worker routine is empty and has following definition:

```
void static CALLBACK WorkerRoutine(DWORD Error, DWORD BytesTransferred, LPWSAOVERLAPPED Overlapped, DWORD InFlags) {}
```

When I pass `NULL` instead of `WorkerRoutine` to the WSARecv method everything works fine. But when I pass completion routine to the call it fails with the error 10022. I tried to use `WorkerRoutine` and `&WorkerRoutine` nothing helps.

the `hEvent` property is set to NULL in the OVERLAPPED_EX object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the I/O completion port associated with file and `lpCompletionRoutine` this is mutually exclusive parameters. you can not use it both at once. when you do this - kernel return `STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER` which is translated to `WSAEINVAL`. so you and must got exactly this error.

the IOCP and ApcRoutine 2 different ways for notify you about operation complete. when you use IOCP - system send packet to IOCP on complete. you need use `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` or `NtRemoveIoCompletion` to extract this packet later. and this is not "poll". from another side if you use `ApcRoutine` system insert apc to your thread. use two ways for notify at once and in concurrent - this is logic error and kernel correct doing when return to you `STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER` in this case.

unfortunately this is not clear stated in MSDN or how minimum i can not fount this. but some research + WRK source code help understand this situation:

`WSARecv` internally call `ZwDeviceIoControlFile` and as result in kernel called [`IopXxxControlFile`](https://github.com/Zer0Mem0ry/ntoskrnl/blob/master/Io/iomgr/internal.c#L8483). when `lpCompletionRoutine != 0` the `ApcRoutine` parameter for `IopXxxControlFile` is present and you fail exactly at [this](https://github.com/Zer0Mem0ry/ntoskrnl/blob/master/Io/iomgr/internal.c#L8667) point:

```
    //
    // If this file has an I/O completion port associated w/it, then ensure
    // that the caller did not supply an APC routine, as the two are mutually
    // exclusive methods for I/O completion notification.
    //

    if (fileObject->CompletionContext && IopApcRoutinePresent( ApcRoutine )) {
        ObDereferenceObject( fileObject );
        return STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER;
}
```

---

also you can allocate m_wsabuf in stack. valid must be only buffer to which point `WSABUF`

> If this function is completed in an overlapped manner, it is the
>   Winsock service provider's responsibility to capture the **WSABUF**
>   structures before returning from this call. This enables applications
>   to build stack-based **WSABUF** arrays pointed to by the *lpBuffers*
>   parameter.

so you can place to `OVERLAPPED_EX` only buffer to which point `WSABUF.buf` but not whole `WSABUF`. but this already not related to your error

Comment: This is not about the files, `clientSocket` tells about sockets. Also here I found example http://www.winsocketdotnetworkprogramming.com/winsock2programming/winsock2advancediomethod5g.html which shows how to use WorkerRoutine with Events and it works. From other side MSDN disagree with them https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741688(v=vs.85).aspx So I confused

Comment: @htonus - socket is file. and i nothing wrote about events. i wrote that iocp and `WorkerRoutine` is mutually exclusive. remove `WorkerRoutine` (set it to 0) if you want use iocp on socket. or not bind socket to iocp if you want use `WorkerRoutine`. all what i wrote is 100% true

Comment: @htonus - simply try think yourself - if you want use `WorkerRoutine` - for what you associated IO completion port with file ? you not need this. from another side - if you have IOCP on file - for what you need `WorkerRoutine` ? remove any of this 2 objects

Comment: @htonus - and i look fast your example - here big logic problem. it use asynchronous `WSARecv` - this is ok. but before this it use synchronous call `accept` (which is wait) which is kill all logic. if you need asynchronous io - use only `AcceptEx` here

Comment: Yes I know that. In my application I use accept on non blocking socket. So It doesn't block execution. Either way, thanks for you comments.

Comment: @htonus - `accept` is block execution or fail. this is visible simply from it signature. it return `SOCKET`. and no way return it in asynchronous. only `AcceptEx` or synchronous call

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157315/discussion-between-htonus-and-rbmm).